# Wpf WebBrowser Refresh

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, refresh, webbrowser-control

I am using `WebBrowser` control in my project.

And i noticed that if the user press right click -> Refresh the

`Navigating`

`LoadCompleted`

not called.

And another strange thing is that after i press the refresh and click another link in the webbrowser the `LoadCompleted` not called too.

This is how i navigate the page in the start :

```
nrowser.Navigate(MYPAGE);
```

Any idea what can be the problem?

Can i fix it with `JavaScript`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle a refresh and differentiate it from navigation. With a little exercise, it can be done by handling DOM `document.onreadystatechange` and `window.onunload` events, as well as the underlying WebBrowser ActiveX control's `NavigateComplete2` and `DownloadBegin` events.

`NavigateComplete2` doesn't get fired for the top `WebBrowser` object when the page is being refreshed, but it does when navigating.  `DownloadBegin` always gets fired, for any download, navigation or refresh activity, possibly multiple times. `window.onunload` gets fired before navigation or refresh, and `document.onreadystatechange` gets fired during navigation or refresh. The rest is the matter of tracking the state transitions. Here is a working example (which still may contain bugs).

**C#:**

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfWebBrowser
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        bool navigating = false;
        bool loading = false;
        bool loaded = false;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            SetBrowserFeatureControl();
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Loaded += (s, e) =>
            {
                var axWebBrowser = (SHDocVw.WebBrowser)GetActiveXInstance(this.webBrowser);

                axWebBrowser.DownloadBegin += delegate
                {
                    HandleDownloadActivity();
                };

                axWebBrowser.NavigateComplete2 += delegate(object pDisp, ref object URL)
                {
                    // top frame?
                    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(axWebBrowser, pDisp))
                    {
                        this.navigating = true;
                        HandleDownloadActivity();
                    }
                };

                this.webBrowser.Navigate("http://example.com");
            };
        }

        // handler for document.readyState == "complete"
        void DomDocumetCompleteHandler(dynamic domDocument)
        {
            dynamic domWindow = domDocument.parentWindow;

            domWindow.attachEvent("onunload", new DomEventHandler(delegate
            {
                this.loaded = false;
                this.loading = false;
            }));

            var navigated = this.navigating;

            this.navigating = false;
            this.loaded = true;
            this.loading = false;

            MessageBox.Show(navigated ? "Navigated" : "Refreshed");
        }

        void HandleDownloadActivity()
        {
            dynamic domDocument = this.webBrowser.Document;
            if (domDocument == null)
                return;

            if (loading || loaded)
                return;

            this.loading = true;

            if (domDocument.readyState == "complete")
            {
                DomDocumetCompleteHandler(domDocument);
            }
            else
            {
                DomEventHandler handler = null;
                handler = new DomEventHandler(delegate
                {
                    if (domDocument.readyState == "complete")
                    {
                        domDocument.detachEvent("onreadystatechange", handler);
                        DomDocumetCompleteHandler(domDocument);
                    }
                });
                domDocument.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", handler);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the underlying WebBrowser ActiveX object;
        /// this code depends on SHDocVw.dll COM interop assembly,
        /// generate SHDocVw.dll: "tlbimp.exe ieframe.dll",
        /// and add as a reference to the project
        /// </summary>
        static object GetActiveXInstance(WebBrowser wb)
        {
            return wb.GetType().InvokeMember("ActiveXInstance",
                BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                null, wb, new object[] { }) as SHDocVw.WebBrowser;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// EventHandler - adaptor to call C# back from JavaScript or DOM event handlers
        /// </summary>
        [ComVisible(true), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch)]
        public class DomEventHandler
        {
            [ComVisible(false)]
            public delegate void Callback(ref object result, object[] args);

            [ComVisible(false)]
            private Callback _callback;

            [DispId(0)]
            public object Method(params object[] args)
            {
                var result = Type.Missing; // Type.Missing is "undefined" in JavaScript
                _callback(ref result, args);
                return result;
            }

            public DomEventHandler(Callback callback)
            {
                _callback = callback;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// WebBrowser version control
        /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx#browser_emulation
        /// </summary>
        void SetBrowserFeatureControl()
        {
            // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330720(v=vs.85).aspx

            // FeatureControl settings are per-process
            var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);

            // make the control is not running inside Visual Studio Designer
            if (String.Compare(fileName, "devenv.exe", true) == 0 || String.Compare(fileName, "XDesProc.exe", true) == 0)
                return;

            // Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE9/IE10 Standards mode.
            SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", fileName, 9000);
        }

        void SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(string feature, string appName, uint value)
        {
            using (var key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(
                String.Concat(@"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\", feature),
                RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree))
            {
                key.SetValue(appName, (UInt32)value, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfWebBrowser.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Width="800" Height="600">
        <WebBrowser Name="webBrowser"/>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Noseratio, it works great. I wrapped what you did into an object that you can just pass the web browser into and handle the events.

```
public class WebBrowserHook
{
    private bool _isNavigating = false;
    private bool _isLoading = false;
    private bool _isLoaded = false;
    private WebBrowser _webBrowser = null;

    public WebBrowserHook(WebBrowser webBrowser)
    {
        _webBrowser = webBrowser;

        _webBrowser.Loaded += (s, e) =>
        {
            try
            {
                var axWebBrowser = (SHDocVw.WebBrowser)GetActiveXInstance(this._webBrowser);

                axWebBrowser.DownloadBegin += delegate
                {
                    HandleDownloadActivity();
                };

                axWebBrowser.NavigateComplete2 += delegate(object pDisp, ref object URL)
                {
                    // top frame?
                    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(axWebBrowser, pDisp))
                    {
                        this._isNavigating = true;
                        HandleDownloadActivity();
                    }
                };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                AppLog.LogException(ex);
            }

        };

    }

    public event EventHandler Navigated;
    public event EventHandler Refreshed;

    public WebBrowser Browser
    {
        get{return _webBrowser;}
    }

    // handler for document.readyState == "complete"
    private void DomDocumentCompleteHandler(mshtml.HTMLDocument domDocument)
    {
        try
        {
            mshtml.HTMLWindow2 domWindow = (mshtml.HTMLWindow2)domDocument.parentWindow;

            domWindow.attachEvent("onunload", new DomEventHandler(delegate
            {
                this._isLoaded = false;
                this._isLoading = false;
            }));

            var navigated = this._isNavigating;

            this._isNavigating = false;
            this._isLoaded = true;
            this._isLoading = false;

            if (navigated)
            {
                if (Navigated != null)
                    Navigated(this, new EventArgs());
            }
            else
            {
                if (Refreshed != null)
                    Refreshed(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AppLog.LogException(ex);
        }
    }

    private void HandleDownloadActivity()
    {
        try
        {
            mshtml.HTMLDocument domDocument = (mshtml.HTMLDocument)this._webBrowser.Document;
            if (domDocument == null)
                return;

            if (_isLoading || _isLoaded)
                return;

            this._isLoading = true;

            if (domDocument.readyState == "complete")
            {
                DomDocumentCompleteHandler(domDocument);
            }
            else
            {
                DomEventHandler handler = null;
                handler = new DomEventHandler(delegate
                {
                    if (domDocument.readyState == "complete")
                    {
                        domDocument.detachEvent("onreadystatechange", handler);
                        DomDocumentCompleteHandler(domDocument);
                    }
                });
                domDocument.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", handler);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AppLog.LogException(ex);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the underlying WebBrowser ActiveX object;
    /// this code depends on SHDocVw.dll COM interop assembly,
    /// generate SHDocVw.dll: "tlbimp.exe ieframe.dll",
    /// and add as a reference to the project
    /// </summary>
    private static object GetActiveXInstance(WebBrowser wb)
    {
        return wb.GetType().InvokeMember("ActiveXInstance",
            BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
            null, wb, new object[] { }) as SHDocVw.WebBrowser;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// EventHandler - adaptor to call C# back from JavaScript or DOM event handlers
    /// </summary>
    [ComVisible(true), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch)]
    public class DomEventHandler
    {
        [ComVisible(false)]
        public delegate void Callback(ref object result, object[] args);

        [ComVisible(false)]
        private Callback _callback;

        [DispId(0)]
        public object Method(params object[] args)
        {
            var result = Type.Missing; // Type.Missing is "undefined" in JavaScript
            _callback(ref result, args);
            return result;
        }

        public DomEventHandler(Callback callback)
        {
            _callback = callback;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you handle the object for refresh, gohome, goback, goforward, stop from main caller class? Do you set the property of the webbrowser source?