# How do I get current status code in a WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, webbrowser-control, http-status-codes

I needed to get http status code from page loaded in the WebBrowser, I ended up with this solution:

I'm using `NavigateError` event from a `WebBrowser` `ActiveXInstance` instance. But it doesn't work properly: I get only a status code in case of an error (obivous, like method name does suggets) if the page can't be loaded and the user `wb.Refresh()` it and load is OK and I have only the old http status error code stored because successfully load doesn't change my http status code. How do I solve this?

```
public doSomething()
{
    SHDocVw.WebBrowser axBrowser = (SHDocVw.WebBrowser)webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance;
    axBrowser.NavigateError += new SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_NavigateErrorEventHandler(axbrowser_navigatorError);
}

public void axbrowser_navigatorError(object pDIsp, ref object URL, ref object frame, ref object statusCode, ref bool Cancel)
{
    statuscodeLabel.Text = statusCode.ToString();
    int.TryParse(statusCode.ToString(), out httpCode);
}
```

Comment: NavigateComplete2 fires when there is no error.  So use it to reset your status code.

Comment: Using this I can just assume no error occured but can't get http status code, since its arguments are `object pDisp, ref object url` where `pDsip` is a `WebBrowser` instance (where we can't get http status code without my `axbrowser_navigatorError()`) and `url` is the url we're handling, right?

Comment: It looks like just to be the WebBrowser's DocumentCompleted equivalent...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WebBrowser`'s `Refresh` is quite different from the `Navigate`/`Navigate2`. There is no `NavigateComplete2` fired for Refresh. I don't think you can get the status code for Refresh unless you resort to some down-level [APP handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767743(v=vs.85).aspx) hooks. Related: [Wpf WebBrowser Refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19362003/1768303).

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the [WebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse(v=vs.110).aspx) from the [NavigationEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) on LoadComplete() this should also trigger when the page is refreshed.

Comment: Is this a method from which class? I can't find it in neither `WebBrowser` or `(SHDocVw.WebBrowser)webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance`. Is this msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.loadcomplete(v=vs.110).aspx the one you're talking about?

Comment: Can you use the WebBrowser control from the Toolbox. This one wraps the ActiveX but adds more control.

Comment: That's what I'm using. Note the cast in the `doSomething()` function. The point you can't get http status code only using a WebBrowser.